# Regex: using a pattern as a variable?

Tags: regex

Say I am trying to match any single lower case letter separated by a colon that repeats itself, say, 5 times (but the last repetition do not have a colon anymore). For example:

```
h:e:l:l:o
```

Something like this would work:

```
[a-z]:{4}[a-z]
```

Is there a better way to do this? Can I somehow reference the first [a-z] in place of the second [a-z]?

Comment: Should be `([a-z]:){4}[a-z]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming PCRE/Javascript,

```
(?!:)((^|:)[a-z]){5}
```

Comment: Oops. Missed the parenthesis. No, that is not what I want. I'm trying to get rid of the last `[a-z]`

Comment: Seems like you also missed the point, this regex is using a lookbehind so it eliminates the first `[a-z]`.  Which is all you need to do here to remove the redundant extra `[a-z]` - In Python/Perl you can create regex references to reuse parts of your regex. (I'm not sure how many other flavors implement this feature though.)